# View source code and sniff images with PHP?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, sniffer

I would like to implement a PHP web page that, given a certain URL, is going to sniff some images from that page.
Do to so, I need :

1) to access the html source-code of that page and find out the URLs of the images I want.

2) to download these images on my FTP

I don't know how to do these two tasks, I guess I will have to use third party libraries, but this is the first time I need to do so and I am not sure.
Any advices ?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look to the PHP DOMDocument. I think it could help you. [link](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a simple task in PHP:

1. Use [`file_get_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to fetch the HTML from any random page ([cURL](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) would work too).
2. Using [`DOMDocument`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), find all `img` tags inside the page (see `getElementsByTagName()` method)
3. Extract the `src` attribute from each node.
4. Download the images somewhere with cURL.
5. Use the [FTP functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to upload them to your server (or use a library [like this one](https://github.com/dg/ftp-php)).

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean grab html page's images and download them and then upload these images to your own `FTP` server?

If I catch on you correctly, this task will be completed by plain `PHP` code, no need of third party libraries.

1. Use `preg_match_all` to match all images out
2. Download them(use `curl` or file_get_content)
3. upload them to your `FTP` server, you can simply use `curl` again, put that image you downloaded above(you don't need save image in your `PHP` located machine, it is a `File Stream` in memory) in `POST` request body then send the request. Or upload image using  `FTP` related functions(find that function in PHP net Document)

**You need do step 2 and 3 in a loop basing on data generated from step 1.**

Tell me if you need help about them.